# Boostrap Column Wrapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap so I must be missing something easy here...

I want to have a grid panels with photos. If the screen is wide enough, I want to show four panels side by side. If it's too narrow I want to show two rows of two.

... so I set up four panels inside divs with the following classes:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
...panel
</div>
```

At medium size and above it works out to a nice four panel wide layout, but at the small size the panels don't line up quite right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDt4F.png

http://www.bootply.com/Ap3qW1cQ6q

Comment: Can you post the rest of your markup please? The bootply link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually never-mind it just started working for me. Odd!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this one you need to use a `clearfix` and a responsive utility class such as `visible-sm` between the second and third columns. You can read up about responsive column resets [here](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

It should look like this:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
</div>
```

This is the updated Bootply link: http://www.bootply.com/NsYQ16DZrf

Comment: Thanks James. That works, but I'm wondering why it is necessary. Shouldn't bootstrap columns just wrap smoothly when you get past 12?

Comment: 9 times out of 10 yes. But this can occur if one columns is taller than another. The Bootstrap docs I linked to has a section on Bootstrap column resets. Its useful to read just in case you find yourself needing to reset offsets in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this, it think? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/5gs8pojm/2/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but with panels inside. It seems whenever i put the panels in there then it starts to act wierd